# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ускорить выполнение программы? И почему она такая медленная?

Tags: python-3.x

Цель программы отделить русский перевод слов от немецкого значения и поместить это в разные списки. Файл, в котором находится всё это выглядит примерно вот так:

das Sedimentgestein осадочная порода

Kernspaltung расщепление атомного ядра

Im Grunde genommen по сути

...

то есть в одной строчке находится сначала значение, а потом перевод.
В целом программа делает то, что мне нужно - разносит значение и перевод по разным спискам в правильной последовательности.

Но код вышел нереально медленным, подскажите, пожалуйста, где может крыться причина этого и возможно ли это исправить?

```
import os
import langdetect



os.chdir(r'C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Документы\help')
slovar=[]
with open('wordd.txt', 'r') as proba:
    for line in proba:
       slovar.append(str(line))
       
lange_slovar=len(slovar)

from langdetect import detect


deut=[]
rus=[]
deut2=[]
rus2=[]
k=0

while k!=lange_slovar:
    a=slovar[k] 
    d=a.split(' ') 
    for word in d:
        try:
            if (detect(str(word))!='uk' and
                detect(str(word))!='ru' and
                detect(str(word))!='mk' and
                detect(str(word))!='bg') :
                
                deut.append(word) #здесь хранится немецкое словосочетание или слово
                
            else:
                rus.append(word) #русское словосочетание или слово
        except:
            pass
    MyString=' '.join(deut) 
    deut2.append(MyString)
    rus2.append(rus)
    deut=[]
    rus=[]
    

    k+=1
    

print(' ')

rus2=[x for x in rus2 if x!=''] #удаление пустых элементов в русском списке, в немецком все ок

import random

a=random.choice(rus2)
for i in a:
   print(i)
```

Comment: Чтобы оптимизировать программу, нужно знать где код медленно выполняется. Вы делали замер времени кусков кода?

Comment: (detect(str(word))!='uk' зачем делать 4 проверки, если в файле только 2 варианта ? я предпологаю что определить язык это очень долго.

Comment: потому что langdetect определяет некоторые русские слова, как болгарские, украинские и тд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Вы как-то странно читаете файл, есть же готовая функция `readlines`, которая вернёт вам сразу весь файл в виде списка строк, самому их не надо читать и в список добавлять
- Но на самом деле вам и не нужен весь файл со словарём в памяти, вы только зря тратите время на добавление в список и т.д., обрабатывайте файл построчно, сразу пускайте строки на обработку, зачем вам промежуточный список?
- Вы много где зачем-то лишний раз преобразуете строку в строку через `str`, это излишне, у вас и так уже строка
- Скорее всего медленно работает функция `detect`, очень рекомендую сделать свою функцию, обёрнутую кэширующим декоратором `lru_cache` и вызывать `detect` через эту функцию. Если слова у вас в файле довольно часто повторяются, это может дать заметное ускорение (в несколько раз, иногда на порядок).
- Вы ещё и вызываете `detect(str(word))` несколько раз подряд во время проверки. Не делайте так. Помещайте результат работы функции в переменную и потом в `if` проверяйте значение этой переменной. Кэширование поможет справиться и с этим, но так лучше не делать никогда.

Пример использования кэширующего декоратора (с применением двух других советов):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def detect_cached(word):
    return detect(word)

...

det = detect_cached(word)
if (det!='uk' and
    det!='ru' and
    det!='mk' and
    det!='bg') :
...
```

Comment: Попробую, спасибо!

Comment: @Jam если не разберетесь как конкретно код написать, напишите сюда, попробую набросать, пока просто некогда

Comment: Добрый вечер! У меня к сожалению не получилось разобраться, как применить @lru_cache,  не могли бы вы немного подробнее объяснить, пожалуйста

Comment: *если что, я могу создать новый вопрос с кодом, в котором уже использованы все советы, кроме четвертого

Comment: @Jam А что именно не получилось? Я вроде все нужные для этого конструкции привёл. Спрашивайте как удобнее, будет время отвечу. Насколько за счёт остальных советов удалось ускориться, интересно? )

Comment: @Jam Так то у меня ещё идеи потом были насчёт ускорения. Если у вас чётко идут сначала только немецкие слова и потом только русские, то можно было бы чем-то типа двоичного поиска водораздел между ними искать, чтобы все слова предложения не детектировать. У меня идей то много, вопрос в том, стоит ли их все пробовать, обычно имеет смысл остановиться при достижении приемлемого времени работы программы. Совершенствовать можно бесконечно.

Comment: К сожалению, действительно проблема лежит в блоке с langdetect (datetime показал, что именно на него уходит +4 секунды) , поэтому другие преобразование не особо помогли выиграть время, хотя все равно были очень полезны

Comment: И вот мой вопрос только уже заданный в виде вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154894/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-no-features-in-text-langdetect

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы смогли посмотреть

Comment: И про двоичный поиск было бы очень интересно узнать