# Почему случается ошибка "No features in text" langdetect?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Цель программы отделить русский перевод слов от немецкого значения и поместить это в разные списки. Файл, в котором находится всё это выглядит примерно вот так:

> das Sedimentgestein осадочная порода
>
> Kernspaltung расщепление атомного ядра
>
> Im Grunde genommen по сути
>
> ...

то есть в одной строчке находится сначала значение, а потом перевод. В целом программа делает то, что мне нужно - разносит значение и перевод по разным спискам в правильной последовательности.

Изначальный код вышел очень медленным, поэтому пытаюсь ускорить его за счет lru_cache, но что-то идёт не так и скорее всего я неправильно использую lru_cache.
В итоге вылезает ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Документы\help\hell1.py", line 28, in
>
> word2=str(detect_cached(word))   File "C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Документы\help\hell1.py", line 23, in
> detect_cached
> return detect(t)   File "C:\Users\write\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langdetect\detector_factory.py",
> line 130, in detect
> return detector.detect() ... raise LangDetectException(ErrorCode.CantDetectError, 'No features in text.')
> langdetect.lang_detect_exception.LangDetectException: No features in
> text.

Код:

```
import os
import langdetect
from functools import lru_cache



os.chdir(r'C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Документы\help')
file=open('wordd.txt', 'r')

from langdetect import detect


deut=[]
rus=[]
deut2=[]
rus2=[]
k=0

@lru_cache(None)
def detect_cached(t):
    return detect(t)

for line in file.readlines(): 
    d=line.split(' ') 
    for word in d:
        word2=detect_cached(word)
        try:
            if (detect(word2)!='uk' and
                detect(word2)!='ru' and
                detect(word2)!='mk' and
                detect(word2)!='bg') :
                
                deut.append(word) #здесь хранится немецкое словосочетание или слово
                
            else:
                rus.append(word) #русское словосочетание или слово
        except:
            pass
    MyString=' '.join(deut) 
    deut2.append(MyString)
    rus2.append(rus)
    deut=[]
    rus=[]
    

    k+=1
    

print(' ')

rus2=[x for x in rus2 if x!=''] #удаление пустых элементов в русском списке, в немецком все ок

import random

a=random.choice(rus2)
for i in a:
   print(i)
```

Comment: В русском и немецком языках используется различный алфавит. Благодаря этому ваша  задача решается в пару строк кода и работать будет на порядок/порядки быстрее ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В issues библиотеки langdetect, [автор ответил](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect/issues/44#issuecomment-335264211) про смысл этой ошибки:

> Error No features in text generally means, that there is no way to
> detect a language on the given input.
>
> For example, when you pass in string (or a number): 222222, what
> language is it? Can't tell, right? Similarly, when you pass just url:
> https://www.mark.cn or whatever.
>
> To throw an exception at that point is the best way to handle such
> inputs. What you want to do is to catch the exception and handle the
> situation accordingly.

Т.е. эта ошибка выбрасывается, когда нет возможности определить язык.

Со стороны пользователя библиотеки, нужно ловить и обрабатывать это исключение

Например, возвращать `None`:

```
@lru_cache(None)
def detect_cached(t):
    try:
        return detect(t)
    except:
        return
```

Если нужно конкретно обрабатывать это исключение:

```
from langdetect.lang_detect_exception import LangDetectException
...

@lru_cache(None)
def detect_cached(t):
    try:
        return detect(t)
    except LangDetectException:
        return
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это было то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт параметра `None` я был ранее неправ - нужен либо он, либо скобки, я почему-то был уверен, что (этот) декоратор можно использовать без скобок и это так прямо и приведено в примерах в документации к каким-то версиям `Python`. Но в других версиях и в текущей версии в `Google Colab` скобки нужны, странно.

Но только не надо делать `detect(word2)`, у вас в `word2` уже есть результат определения языка, его и надо сравнивать с 'uk' и т.д. Перечитайте мой код из ответа вам на предыдущий вопрос.

Кстати, сравнения тоже можно перенести в кеширующую функцию и возвращать оттуда уже true/false для if, но это только после того как разберетесь с текущим кодом делайте, а то запутаетесь.

А в главном уважаемый @gil9red совершенно прав - ошибка была при невозможности детектировать язык и надо было это обернуть в `try/catch`.

Вообще, судя по всему, данная библиотека очень плохо детектирует языки, потестируйте на ваших данных [другие библиотеки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106810/8324991)

Comment: Хоть функция с if пока еще не перенесена в кэширующую, но уже время очень значительно уменьшилось с 4.3 до 1.3. В общем, спасибо большое за совет  c lru_cache! и за detect(word2), вечная невнимательность

Comment: @Jam Ну, скорее всего это уже не даст особого выигрыша, просто так будет правильнее с точки зрения архитектуры и знаний на будущее. В вашем случае вообще может быть достаточно смотреть диапазон, в котором находится первая буква слова и по нему уже можно определять язык без всяких библиотек. Но это надо тестировать.

Comment: Я переписала функцию без langdetect, она сравнивает первый и второй символ с латинским алфавитом, и время уменьшилось просто до 0,1 секунд. Поэтому больше спасибо за этот совет